# GPU problems with 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, gpu, gpu-driver

Ok so.. this is probably a noobish question but I'll ask anyways cause I can't figure this out....

[Backstory]
I got an old PC from a garage sale a couple of days ago and decided to turn it into a small test server when I turned it on it booted up to windows xp happily and I decided to install Linux

I've had a laptop that was on Ubuntu so I decided to install Ubuntu after going to ubuntu.com and downloading Ubuntu 16.04tls (32bit)

When I went to install the os I was surprised that the mouse was 'invisible' when I finished installing it (using the keyboard and some guessing) it asked me to restart I did and now I have this:

[PROBLEM]

When I turn the PC on it boots normally and it asks for my password when I enter it everything except the wallpaper and the Ubuntu logo (in the down left corner) disappears and it stays like that for 10-15min and then the side bar with the icons and the top bar with the clock and stuff shows but the wallpaper becomes black and if I try to open a program ... Nothing still black it shows that the program is open but the screen is black also I don't have a mouse ... Strangely the start menu works and the power down box renders correctly

When I removed my graphics card (an old envidia GeForce 500 (I think) it works just fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your old Windows XP PC doesn't need a graphics card to run a server without a GUI. Install [Ubuntu Server 32-bit](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads) the default way so that it runs text-only without a desktop environment. If the graphics card continues to cause problems you can remove it.

The standard system requirements for Ubuntu Server 16.04 are frugal.

- 1 GHz processor
- 512 MB of system memory (RAM)
- 1 GB of disk space (base system)
- 1.75 GB of disk space (all tasks installed)
- Monitor capable of 640x480